# Get record by value Erlang/Mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How does one get records -- by value -- in a more efficient way?

Currently I’m doing this:

```
Coupon = [P || P <- kvs:all(company_coupon), P#company_coupon.company_id == C#company.id],
```

My question is geared at kvs:all(...). In databases it is usually pretty expensive to get all entries first and then match them.

Is there a better way?

PS: "lists:keyfind" also needs to be provided with ALL records first, to then run them through the loop.

How are you guys doing it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One can use kvs:index(table, field, value) if one has set the field as a key before:

```
#table{name=user,fields=record_info(fields,user), keys = [field]}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a functional language like erlang or lisp, traversing data is unavoidable in most of cases while sql doesn't need it. So it is better to do it with sql if you are storing data in a database like postgres that supports the sql but if you don't need to save data, you are in the correct way.

Comment: I don't see how SQL is related to functional programming languages here. You can make SQL queries from any popular functional language.